# Fetch call in ReactJS to PHP file returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs, react-router

When I run a fetch call from within my `componentDidMount()` method, it returns `undefined`.  The PHP file returns JSON no problem when I run it manually on a server but the call itself is what returns `undefined`.

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("backend.php").then(function (data) {
            console.log("Hello");
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
```

My console says:

```
App.js:60 Hello
App.js:61 undefined
```

However if I navigate to `backend.php` in my browser i get

```
[{"ID":"0","Name":"Hulk","Publisher":"Marvel","Date":"2019-04-02","Number":"1"},{"ID":"1","Name":"Hulk","Publisher":"Marvel","Date":"2019-04-02","Number":"2"}]
```

Here is my PHP file

```php
$result_array = array();
/* Create connection */
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
/* Check connection  */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection to database failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
/* SQL query to get results from database */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Comics ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
/* If there are results from database push to result array */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($result_array, $row);
    }
}
/* send a JSON encded array to client */
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result_array);
$conn->close();
```

Due to difficulties figuring this question out I have added this for you guys to see. This is what returns if I tell it it is text using `.then(response => response.text())`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/main.c69debfe96d2803a0c36.hot-update.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open up the network tab in your browser and try making the call again, this will give you a list of resources being loaded (including backend.php) and you can see what server responses you're getting.

Comment: what am i looking for? i see that backend.php is an initiator for a bunch of things but that is it.

Comment: Make the request from the React component with the network tab open and one of the items in the list should be called backend.php. Click on that and you'll see the actual response and headers which will help you determine what's up.

Comment: What's the `Content-Type` header of the `backend.php` response? You probably want `application/json`.

Comment: got that already

Comment: the headers appear to be all empty @DanielG

Comment: @Caleb Just for reference, which browser are you using? I want to make sure my directions work for your situation.

Comment: Chrome browser. Interesting enough, if i add response.text() it prints out the page to the console

Comment: still can't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using npm to compile this, and you have the PHP file in the src directory of the npm project. Try moving the PHP file into the root folder of the project (with the src, public, and build folder) and referencing it as `../backend.php`.

Note: if you are using `npm start`, it won't work as the npm server can't run PHP. You will need to compile it using `npm run build` and then use a web server that supports PHP.

Comment: how do i run it on a server and not though npm

Comment: `npm run build`

Answer (score 2):

When using fetch and using promises with this fetch, you have the chain a couple of things to get the right json like this:

```
fetch('backend.php')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
          // Do something with your json
     })
```

Or to debug the response you can do

```
fetch('backend.php')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
         console.log(text);
         // do something else with the text
    })
```

Comment: When i run it i get: Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Looks like you are getting some HTML response there. Can you check in the "Developer tools" usually F12, and check the "Network" tab. For the "backend.php" network interaction you should see the response. Check it's valid json.

Comment: its showing my index page as the response. literally a bunch of html like i requested to see view-source.

Comment: Right, there is the error. You probably have to find the right way to call backend.php

Comment: Check the path to backend.php is correct. It must be at the same level where you triggering the javascript code. Otherwise do something like this `fetch('<right-path-to-your-script>/backend.php')...`

Comment: when i run the fuill address C:\ etc. i get: Parsing error: Octal literal in strict mode. Sorry we are getting a bit in the weeds here.

Comment: Try a relative path. `fetch("/backend.php")` maybe?

Comment: Write those paths between single quotes. Do you still get the Octal stuff?

Comment: ya. i tried double quotes b/c it did it with single quotes.  Just a note. I am running it inside my App.js file.  backend.php is located in the same folder with it. Relative path doesnt change a thing.

Comment: Right. Are you using some kind of framework for the php? It looks like you are missing hitting the `backend.php`. Maybe the place where you have the App.js is not in a server environment. Or if you have it on a localhost do something like `http://localhost/backend.php` or add another full url to the local server where you have this setup.

Comment: Try the full url. Copy it from the address bar that actually returns json when you hit it through the browser

Comment: the full url does not work. the folder fro the project is in the www directory of wamp server and then i start it up there

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your folder structure for this project?